# Что значит такой синтаксис

Tags: javascript, typescript

Разбираюсь в коде проекта и нашел подобный блок кода:

```js
class Test {
   async function foo(): Promise<void> {
      // здесь идут инструкции, которые ничего не возвращают
   }
}
```

Что здесь означает Promise<void>? Для меня было бы понятно, если бы возвращалось отдельно void либо отдельно Promise. Что означает такой синтаксис?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TypeScript и дженерики(generic)

возможно вы не понимаете значение "скобочек" `T<any>`

```
type $qwa<T> = () => T

q: {
  const qwa: $qwa<string> = null as any
  const res = qwa() // const res: string
}
q: {
  const qwa: $qwa<number> = null as any
  const res = qwa() // const res: number
}
q: {
  //  и т.д. и т.п.
}
```

### async function = Promise

1. промис не обязан что-то возвращать
2. иногда нужно что-то сделать только после того, как отработает функция/ии
3. `async function` = промис
4. возможно у вас внутри используется `await`
   https://learn.javascript.ru/async-await

```
let data: string | null = null

async function loadData(): Promise<void> {
  // здесь идут инструкции, которые ничего не возвращают
  data = 'DATA'
}

console.log(`данные не загружены`, { data })

loadData().then(() => {
  console.log(`данные загружены`, { data })
})
```

### пример

загрузка нескольких картинок и только после этого отрисовка их на странице

```js
"use strict";
let imageList = [];
let counter = 0;
function loadImage() {
    return new Promise(r => {
        const timeout = getRandomInt(3, 6) * 1000;
        const id = ++counter;
        const name = `image ${id}`;
        setTimeout(() => {
            r({ id, name });
        }, timeout);
    });
}
async function load() {
    const image = await loadImage();
    imageList.push(image);
    console.log(`загруженна картинка № ${image.id}`);
}
Promise
    .all([
    load(),
    load(),
    load(),
    load(),
    load(),
])
    .then(() => {
    console.log(`все картинки загруженны. количество картинок ${counter}`);
});
function getRandomInt(min = 0, max = 9) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Comment: Т.е. такой (Promise<void>) синтаксис справедлив только для промисов? Не приходят в голову другие варианты)

Comment: добавил в ответ "TypeScript и дженерики(generic)"